# Помогите пожалуйста с задачей!

Tags: python, python-3.x

Дано натуральное число n, (n≥10). Напишите программу, которая определяет его максимальную и минимальную цифры.

Формат входных данных
На вход программе подается одно натуральное число.

Формат выходных данных
Программа должна вывести максимальную и минимальную цифры введенного числа (с поясняющей надписью).

Sample Input 1:

26670

Sample Output 1:

Максимальная цифра равна 7

Минимальная цифра равна 0

Мой ответ:

```
n = int(input())
n = list(str(n))
print(str('Максимальная цифра равна '), max(n), str('Минимальная цифра равна '), min(n), sep='\n')
```

Comment: 1. зачем переводить imput в число, чтобы потом перевести в строку? 2. зачем переводить строку в список, если вы не собираетесь ее изменять? 3. зачем переводить явный текст в принте в строковый формат. 4. что вас не устраивает в вашем ответе?

Comment: Не устраивает вывод, ответ иной иначе  я сюда за помощью не обратился бы)))

Comment: Ну и конечно докину код однострочник: `print("Min letter is: {0}, max letter is: {1}".format(*(lambda a: (min(a), max(a)))(list(input()))))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
a = list(map(int, input()))
print(f"Максимальная цифра равна {max(a)}\nМинимальная цифра равна {min(a)}")
```

Comment: скинь номер телефона)

Comment: Аууууу!!!!!!!!!

Comment: разглашение личных данных это плохая затея

Comment: я из благих намерение

Answer (score 0):

```
n = int(input())
n = list(str(n))
print(str(max(n), min(n), sep='\n')
```

Comment: с поясняющей надписью!!!

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: @gipotezaizgaza, знаете, есть еще слово пожалуйста. Требовать тут вы не имеете права.